# Getting hours and minutes from start and endDate using Moment Js

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I am trying to come up with a way that I can get the number of minutes between 8am and 5pm using momment.   From there, I want to be able to breakdown those minutes into set of 45 and 75 (maybe like an array or so, dont know yet).

This is what I have using momentJs

```
let startdate = moment().set({"hour": 8, "minute": 00});
let closingDate = moment().set({"hour": 17, "minute": 00});
```

This gives me what i need, but is there a way that I can break that down into how many 45min fit between startDate and closingDate?

Comment: let startdate = moment().set({"hour": 8, "minute": 00});
let closingDate = moment().set({"hour": 17, "minute": 00}); total_45Min = (closingDate.diff(startdate))/(1000*60*45) is this what you are looking ?

Comment: closingDate.diff(startdate,'minutes')/45 or  closingDate.diff(startdate,'minutes')/75

Comment: @sandeepjoshi yes, thats it, thank you so much!

Comment: Please read  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution since by the time you replied i was done with this :)

```js
let startdate = moment().set({"hour": 8, "minute": 00});
let closingDate = moment().set({"hour": 17, "minute": 00});
console.log(startdate.local())
console.log(closingDate.local())
let totalintervals_45 = 0
while(startdate.add(moment.duration(45,'minutes'))<closingDate){
console.log(startdate.local())
totalintervals_45++;
}

console.log("total interval of 45 mins: "+totalintervals_45)
console.log("---------------------------")
startdate = moment().set({"hour": 8, "minute": 00});
let totalintervals_75 = 0
while(
startdate.add(moment.duration(75,'minutes'))<closingDate){
console.log(startdate.local())
totalintervals_75++;
}

console.log("total interval of 75 mins: "+totalintervals_75)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```